# List old/not present NICs in Windows with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, network-programming, wmi

What is the most reliable method to filter not-present network adapters (greyed out in Device Manager with "View hidden devices" option on)?

I checked **win32_NetworkAdapter** class and these properties don't seem to provide much help:

**ServiceName** - if it's $null the adapter still may be a "valid" system device, like Microsoft tunnel adapters, Bluetooth, etc.

**Availability** - I got value "3" for both active/present and not present (which is weird).

**Installed** - as above, "True" for both types.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Get-NetAdapter -Name "*" -IncludeHidden
```

Comment: This cmdlet is available only starting from Windows 8/2012+, that's why I actually use get-ciminstance (or even get-wmiobject). But if used, it still shows irrelevant results (working NICs, ISATAP adapters etc. - all except the needed adapters).